# Will a Flash .swf file execute a .exe file on Mac?

Tags: flash, text-files, flash-cs4, adobe-director

I am busy updating a Flash application from a previous developer, but it was written for Windows. I am busy developing on Mac and there is this segment of code:

```
_global.localSO = SharedObject.getLocal("personalCookie", "/");
_global.localSO.data.name = textFileContent;
_global.localSO.flush();
fscommand("exec", "fscommand/save_personal.exe");
```

What it basically does is the following:

- it stores a value to a session variable in Flash (was told this by previous developer)
- it calls a file compiled from Director, `save_personal.exe`
- `save_personal.exe` calls another `fl_save_personal.swf` inside the .exe file
- `fl_save_personal.swf` retrieves the session variables and passes them to the `save_personal.exe`
- `save_personal.exe` writes this variable to a text file `personal.txt` (as it gets it with no other calculations on the variable itself)

Now, my real question is the following, can this `save_personal.exe` execute on a Mac at all (by means of the original Flash app calling it, in this case `myApplication.app`), or must I publish the Director file as `save_personal.app` also in order to test the file creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.EXE on MAC? NO!
only if you use [Wine for darwin](http://davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/) :)

i think that this can help too: board[dot]flashkit[dot]com/board/showthread.php?t=140971

Comment: I am not necessarily going to double click the actual .exe file, it will only be called from my Flash .swf/.app movie.

Yes, I know Mac cannot execute .exe files, but I was just wondering if it can be done via a known application (like a .swf) that it does actually understand how to execute.

Comment: i think no, because the swf just calls the file to be executed, and it will not handle the system to say how to execute it.
so, if you wan't to run an exe file on mac, no matter if it is called by Finder or Adobe Flash Player, you will need a handler, like Wine for Darwin or CrossOver ;)

I've edited the answer

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to know. Well, it works if I replace `save_personal.exe` with `save_personal.app`.